# Using TileMap in cocos2dx

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am creating a CrossPlatform ( iOS & android ) using Cocos2dX.I have a single TileMap

Details:

Rows & column : 8 X 11

TileSize Each : 192

TileMapSize   : 1728 X 2304

TileSheet     : tileMap.jpg ( 964 X 1736)

I scale down the TileMap accordingly for iOS devices(e.g.:iPad - 0.44) to fit in the window and used Resolution Policy:**kResolutionFixedHeight**. It works as i expected the height stretches according to device height.But as expected their is a loss in width.

So My question is am i going in right direct using single TileMap for all devices or should i use three or more TileMaps.

If then please tell me the Tile Map size used for 
iPad,iPhone,iPhone 5,retina or anything else to move Forward

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This map is huge, have you checked whether it renders correctly with all tiles set? Don't know about cocos2d-x but in cocos2d-iphone the max tilemap size was 16,384 tiles (128x128, single layer). Also memory usage may be an issue here. Assuming a moderately low 32 Bytes of memory per tile, you're looking at over 120 MB of total memory usage.

Comment: Thanks,so now i am creating Tile map for size 768 X 1152 for ipad and so forth.. will it be correct

Answer (score 0):

That's a Massive TileMap, as the comment under your question :)

When I ported a game to Android, I used 3 TileMaps. All maps 15 x 10 tiles, with 32, 64 and 128 pixel tiles.

On App start up, I have:

```
CCSize visibleSize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getVisibleSize();
CGameManager::Instance()->SetSuffixAndScaleFactor(visibleSize);
```

Where SetSuffixAndScaleFactor() is in my CGameManager class. This looks at the screen size,and depending on the resolution sets

1. The tileMaps to be used
2. the ScaleFactor required

Beware of different X and Y scalings - otherwise your tiles will appear stretched.

For the iPad / iPhone....

iPhone is the same as the android tilemaps - 960 x 640 or 480 x 320.

For the iPhone 5 I add a small frame, as with all android devices that don't have a 960 x 640 aspect ratio.

I made a special set for the iPad with 15 x 12 tiles, again one for each resolution.

Comment: Thanks , i created separate tileMaps for iPad-HD,iPhone-SD,iphone5 and used it according to FrameSize(Devices)..it was smooth